# MySQL: Can't update existing NULL value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a weird issue which I'm sure is because I don't understand all the idiosyncrasies of MySQL :(

I have a table with a column that has the default value of `NULL`, "TeamID". When I add a new row without giving a value for that column, it is `NULL`. Perfect. Except when I wish to update that row, the following code doesn't seem to change the value from `NULL` (or even cause any error):

```
    $STH = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE UserDetails SET 
            TeamID = ':teamID' WHERE UserID = ':userID';");
    $STH->execute($params);
```

To restate the problem: I have a problem overwriting TeamID with a non-nullable value if it's already `NULL`. I can't see where there's any error in the code itself, so I'm imagining it's something to do with the `NULL` value.

One problem coding with PHP/MySQL is that you can't step through your code and look at the contents of the database at the same time -- because PHPMyAdmin gets stepped through, too.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So TeamID is NULL and not being updated?

Comment: @BD. Yep, that's exactly correct.

Comment: And I assume userID is not null?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: You should be able to step through your code. Set xdebug to only run on trigger, then get the Chrome or Firefox plugins so that you can enable it only on specific pages.

Comment: @Mark I can step through my code fine. I can't step through my code AND look at the contents of the database in real time -- because PHPMyAdmin uses PHP.

Comment: `':teamID'`  => `:teamID`, lose the quotes, around _every_ single placeholder, doesn't matter which type.

Comment: @Wrikken Thank you!!! That was it. Put it into an answer and I'll give you the points.

Comment: PDO does some emulation in some cases, I usually disable that, might have something to do with it (mind you, what if I want to store the _string_ `:var` in a field? `':var'` should insert the literal `:var`, not go looking for a parameter `:var`). Casting-wise this would be: `':var'` (enter value=>) `'NULL'` (cast to int =>) `0` And @Farray was a bit earlier with the answer, although maybe a little less explicit/clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem may lie in using quote marks around the parameters.  Since you're using a PDO prepared statement with params, you don't have to quote your strings.  I'm not sure how PDO represents `null`, but you might end up in a situation where you try to set `SET TeamID = ''` or `SET TeamID = 'null'` and, depending on the column type, that may not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put quotes around named parameters with PDO:

```
$STH = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE UserDetails SET 
            TeamID = ':teamID' WHERE UserID = ':userID';");
$STH->execute($params);
```

`UserID` will never equal the string `':userID'`, so nothing gets updated.

To ensure that your parameters are interpreted, remove the quotes, like this:

```
$STH = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE UserDetails SET 
            TeamID = :teamID WHERE UserID = :userID");
$STH->execute($params);
```

Comment: MySql (in its default config?) will equate 1 with '1', so `UserID = '12345'` would return the appropriate record.  Same thing goes for setting.  You can `UPDATE...SET col = '1'` even if col's type is int.  However, you'd get an error with `UPDATE...SET col = ''` on the same column.